# react-redux: Getting error 'dispatch is not a function' during 'connect'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to react-redux, working on redux sample. I'm able to render the view properly on browser. But, when I try to initiate an action event, I get the following error message:

> dispatch is  not function

[image]

in the browser's console.

I'm unable to figure out what went wrong. All my source code is below.

How can I figure out what went wrong?

**index.js**

```
const css = require('./assets/main.scss');
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {App} from './container/app';
import reducer from './reducer'

const store = createStore(reducer, 1);

const mountNode = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>, mountNode)
```

**under 
container/app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as MathActions from "./../action/action";
import Calculator from "./../components/calc";

export const App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        const { value, dispatch } = this.props;   
        const actions = bindActionCreators(MathActions, dispatch);
        return (
            <Calculator actions={actions} value={value} />
        );
    }
});

export default connect(
    state => ({ value: state})
)(App);
```

**under action/action.js**

```
import * as types from './actionConstant';

export function addOne() {
    return {
        type: types.ADD_ONE
    };
}

export function subtractOne() {
    return {
        type: types.SUBTRACT_ONE
    };
}

export function doubleValue() {
    return {
        type: types.DOUBLE_VALUE
    };
}
```

**under action/actionConstant.js**

```
export const ADD_ONE = "ADD_ONE";
export const SUBTRACT_ONE = "SUBTRACT_ONE";
export const DOUBLE_VALUE = "DOUBLE_VALUE";
```

**under reducer/index.js**

```
import * as types from './../action/actionConstant';

export default function(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_ONE:
            return state + 1;
        case types.SUBTRACT_ONE:
            return state - 1;
        case types.DOUBLE_VALUE:
            return state * 2;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**under components/calc.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        const { actions } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="calculator">
                <p>{this.props.value}</p>
                <button onClick={actions.addOne}>+1</button>
                <button onClick={actions.subtractOne}>-1</button>
                <button onClick={actions.doubleValue}>{String.fromCharCode(215)}2</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**dependencies in my package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) provides `dispatch` as a property for React component, but anyway there is better (and default to `react-redux`) approach to map action creators to `dispatch`: through `mapDispatchToProps` function that needs to be passed as second argument to `connect`.

So your code can look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as MathActions from "./../action/action";
import Calculator from "./../components/calc";

export const App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        const {value, actions} = this.props;
        return (
            <Calculator actions={actions} value={value}/>
        );
    }
});

export default connect(
    state => ({value: state}),
    dispatch => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(MathActions, dispatch), 
    })
)(App);
```

Comment: how the action is dispatched through in calculator component?

Comment: @maniR You already have calls like `onClick={actions.addOne}` into your component, it will be the same.

Comment: when i tried this approach. when i click and call any action event, it throws error like actions is undefined.

Comment: Sounds strange. Try to dump `MathActions` (it should be object of functions), then dump  `actions` property inside your `App` component and see that it is also object of functions with same keys as in `MathActions`

Comment: congratulations :)